# How to make invisible countdown, that continiues after the page is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, counter

The main idea is when the user click a button, to start counting down on a not displayed counter and set element style display none of the button and display inline-block of a paragraph, that notifies you the button is clicked. When the countdown scores 0, the button is again shown. If you close the page, counter is keep going counting down. If you close the page, and open it again, and the counter isn't on 0, yet it displays another message to tell you wai more. Please help! How do I do that?

Comment: As soon as the page is closed, your JavaScript code is killed. You can keep track of where the timer was at when the session was killed with a cookie or localStorage, but there's no way to keep a timer going while a session is severed.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:

- Store the date and time when you start in localStorage
- <strike>At each counter interval, store the step (min, sec, etc.) in localStorage</strike>
- At page load, read back the stored values, compute and set your button and message accordingly

*As [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362536/brad) commented, you actually only need to store the start timestamp*

Comment: Storing the counter AND the time sounds like the winning combo.

Comment: You only need the starting timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

When the user comes to the website, check for a localstorage variable which will be a timestamp or it will be undefined if it is not set. If the user has been to the site before and the timestamp variable is present in local storage, you can do a time diff from now and the timestamp to calculate how much time is left on the countdown for display purposes. Once time expires, delete the local storage variable. If the user has NOT been to the page before and has not clicked the button, once they click the button...go ahead and set a localstorage variable which is a timestamp of when the button was clicked.

Comment: No need for a server in this case.  We have `localStorage`.